# how to retrieve json data that came from a php numical array?

Tags: jquery

how to retrieve json data that was converted from a php numical array using jquery? I have this php numical array....

```
                      while(tests < totalResults)
                      {
                          $testResults[$columnIndex] = '<p>' . $log_info . '</p>';
                      }
                      $jsonData = json_encode($testResults);
                      echo $jsonData;
```

This is how I retrieve the above php code using jquery but not outing anything...

```
                 $.getJSON("test.php",function(data)
                {
                      $.each(data, function(key, value)
                      {
                         $("#test li:eq(0)").appendTo(value[key]);
                      });
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `value` parameter is not the array, it's the value from that item of the array.

```
$("#test li:eq(0)").appendTo(value);
```

Note that you are creating elements from the string in the array, adding a child to them, and throwing them away. Perhaps you want to use the `append` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change `value[key]` to just `value` because second argument in the loop callback points to the current value of the array. Try this

```
$.getJSON("test.php",function(data)
                {
                      $.each($(data), function(key, value)
                      {
                         $("#test li:eq(0)").appendTo(value);
                      });
                });
```